# The old "Greek Parse" font Filename

Tags: resource-request, greek

Decades ago, before Unicode, I created a number of documents using a font called "Greek Parse." I now want to access this information, but I cannot find a place to download this old font. Does anyone know the actual filename of this old font? I probably have it on an old backup drive, but I have no idea what its filename was.

Anyone know the filename or where you can actually download it today?

EDIT: I found it!  GREEKPAR.TTF  I have it! It works!

Comment: This does not appear to be a question about Christianity. That said, it sounds like your problem is merely solving a basic character substitution cipher, which should not be that difficult, especially if you have some notion of what the documents contain. There may even be tools that can help automate the process, but this is not the correct SE to ask for such advice.

Comment: @Matthew Well, the files are all regarding the Greek New Testament (or Greek Septuagint Old Testament.) So I figured people here would have used this font in the past.

Comment: I agree with @Matthew that since the knowledge to find the file doesn't need any expertise in Greek or Septuagint this seems to belong in Superuser SE.  I tried to tag it to work for this site, but we'll let the community decides.

Comment: Well, after searching for hours, and then posting my question, I found the filename and the file on one of my old backup drives. Here it is GREEKPAR.TTF So thanks anyway.

Comment: @Harvey Is that the same as the file in the first link in my answer?  If so, you can accept the answer.

Comment: Hello! We don't put "solved" in question titles on this site, but if your question has been answered you can click on the green tick beside the answer.

Comment: I think this question is OK - better than questions about 80's cassettes at least.

Answer (score 3):

The filename is GREEKPAR.TTF, used in several older Bible softwares such as [GRAMCORD for Windows](http://gramcord.org/gramwin.htm).  [Their manual](http://www.gramcord.org/ftp/Manuals/GRAMCORD_manual/GRAMCORD%20Manual.pdf) mentions the font and how to use it (page 16).

Searching Google with keywords `Greek parse font` yields two candidates to download the TrueType Font (ttf) file:

- https://ufonts.com/download/greek-parse.html
- http://faithofjesuschrist.com/pages/Fonts

*Warning*: the 2 files are different, so you may need to choose the correct one.

Then if you need to convert the encoded text to Unicode, you can use this guide from Logos Bible Software: https://www.logos.com/grow/how-to-convert-the-greek-parse-font-to-unicode/ .

Good luck !

Comment: I had already done the Google search and got to that site several times but with no success on actually downloading anything. But I have now found it on one of my old drives and it works. The name is GREEKPAR.TTF and a Google search for that name brings up other possibilities for download (but I have it now so I don't need to try downloading.)